# Does the python interpreter use any form of caching in evaluating list concatenations?

Tags: python

I would like to know whether it is safe to write the following

```
from math import e
values = [e ** x for x in range(-10,+11)]
normalized_values = [value/sum(values) for value in values]
```

or should I calculate `sum(values)` upfront and store it in a variable ?

Comment: `values = [math.e**(x/10) for x in range(-50,51)]`, `total = sum(values)`, then `normalized_values = [x/total for x in values]`. I don't know why you are constructing `xs` or the `lambda`.

Comment: @Chad because I copied this snippet from a program in which I used those variables for plotting purposes. My apologies, I should have cleaned the code better up.. I will do this now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No caching is done.  The target expression (`value/sum(values)` in this case) is reevaluated every time.  If you want to precalculate some part of it, you need to do that yourself as you described.